# SQL Server Service Broker: how to determine overhead or max performance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, service-broker

We are trying to determine whether we are using Service Broker appropriately and getting the max performance out of it.  We have been tweaking our SB conversations and handling, and have gone from 3000/minute to 8000/minute, but CPU has stayed constant at 100%.  Additionally, on some days the SB queue stays empty, but on similar-traffic days the queue can back up by 500k.

The machine is a quad-quad (16 cores), no HT, 32gb RAM and 26gb assigned to SQL Server, with AWE enabled.

SQL Server 2008 SP1 (no CUs), Enterprise Edition.
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7600: )

The messages are inserted into a service broker queue, which pulls groups of messages and runs them through a CLR, which parses the XML (not a simple parse, alas) and inserts into a table.  The CLR is considerably faster than our T-SQL code.

We have an average of 35 runnable tasks per scheduler

We run nightly stats/index maintenance.

We have set server MAXDOP = 1 to try and help performance.

We've upped our number of tempdb files to 64 to avoid SGAM contention, which combined with TF1118 seems to have stopped TEMPDB contention.

Looking at sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks, we typically have ~60 tasks waiting on THREADPOOL, with only a handful on other types.

Our signal waits are 70% (resource waits = 30%).

We've verified that the TokenAndUserPermCache stays under 20mb.

Looking at sys.dm_os_latch_stats, we see 40-200k BUFFER latches in 1 minute, which are mostly on sysdesend and a user table we use to deal with Dialogs.

We also see high SOS_SCHEDULER_WAIT, which also indicates CPU pressure.  But is that because of the CLR being freakishly busy, or because of Service Broker overhead?  I'll happily provide code - let me know what I need to post here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will want to consider reposting this to serverfault.com - that's a site for admins.  You may still get an answer here, but StackOverflow is normally more geared towards coding (like SQL Queries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do you use SSB only as a local queueing/processing mechanism, or is there any remote message delivery (x-machine transmission) involved?
2. How many queues?
3. Is Activation involved, I assume yes, how many max_queue_readers?
4. Anything you can asscoiate with the 500k spikes? How long does it take for them to drain?

Some shots in the dark:

- If you see buffer latch contention around sysdesend/sysderecv you can try this: [Service Broker Whitepaper on MSDN: the 150 trick](http://rusanu.com/2009/03/25/service-broker-whitepaper-on-msdn-the-150-trick/).
- Make sure ghost cleanup is up to the task, see [Dealing with Large Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/09/dealing-with-large-queues/). Does `Skipped Ghost Records/sec` go off the charts?

~60 tasks waiting for workers on a 16 CPU machine ... I woudl normally consider OK, but for a machine dedicated to SSB processing is a bit weird, as such machines tend to have few long running tasks (the activated jobs) as opposed to many short running ones, so they don't tend to show THREADPOOL waits.

Comment: Howdy!  Been reading your blog for ideas, but hadn't seen the "Dealing with Large Queues".  (apologies for the formatting)       To answer your questions: 1) local only.  We're feeding it with MSMQ.  2) 2 queues, I believe.  3) not sure, will check.  4)  Not a spike, just a gradual climb (same on the SB feeding it).  Can't associate it with anything.  Once traffic slows down, it can process up to 10k/minute, so the SB queue can clear within an hour.  Aware (but not using) the 150 trick - trying to figure out how to implement. Skipped ghost all the way up to 500k/s. (more in another response)

Comment: We also raised the size of the "batch" that we're pulling from the queue for processing, from 100 to 1000.  That seems to really have improved performance, dramatically so.  We did see that sysdesend was one of the top latchers.

Comment: How big is the average message body size?

Comment: btw, at 500k skipped ghosts/sec, I would pursue further to understand if ghost cleanup keeps up with the queues. Start by looking in sys.allocation_units total pages for the queue(s) data, compare with rows in sys.partitions. Does the total_page*8kb divided by row count give something near avg. message size? If the result is significantly larger than the avg. message size, it means you have large number of ghosts.

Comment: 100 msgs/batch is small. 1000 is the usual sweet spot.